# trying to establish remote connection to home router (to perform Wake on Lan from this router)

Tags: networking, router, openvpn, wake-on-lan

sorry if such topic was already covered, but for now I could not find a solution.
I'm trying to set up Wake on WAN - start my computer (I will call it PC1) - from a remote location over the internet (let's call it PC2).
I read that the solution here is to configure port forwarding on router, and additionally IP/MAC binding to make sure that Wake-on-LAN magic packet will reach the computer PC1 we try to start remotely.
But I read too that port forwarding is not totally secure, and in addition to that my Router (a TP-Link Archer A6) is sitting behind a Huawei HG8120H ONT. Internet (external) adress of Router is 192.168.100.4, which is a private IP. So my Router is behind a NAT, and my computer PC1 is sitting behind a double NAT:

**optical cable from ISP -> Huawei HG8120H ONT -> TP-Link Archer A6 Router -> PC1.**

So I though (maybe it's wrong) that the best way to go there is to connect remotely (through Internet) to my Router, and from router push the Wake-On-LAN magic packet.
For that, I enabled OpenVPN server on TP-Link router (it's a build-in feature of this router), generated the certificate, exported the configuration file, and on the remote location (PC2) I installed OpenVPN client and imported this configuration file generated on router.
But from remote PC2, OpenVPN fails to connect to router - it seems that config file contains IP 192.168.100.4 (external IP of Router), so obviously remote location fails to connect to it.

What I'm doing wrong here?
Or in such situation (Wake on WAN a computer which is behind a double NAT), maybe there is another way to achieve that? I read about having another device (like a Raspberry Pi) on the same network as PC1 and always turned on to perform Wake on LAN from this device, but it's not possible in my situation.

Many thanks in advance for your advices !

Here a screenshot from my Router web interface:

[router web UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCXBw.png)

P.S.: I have some general knowledges in networking, but I'm not an expert at all.

Comment: 192.168.100.4, isn’t a public IP address, that iP address doesn’t exist outside of your intranet network

Comment: Thanks for answer ! yes 192.168.100.4 is obviously a private IP address. So as explained in my question, the PC I want to start remotely over internet is sitting behind a double NAT (router + Huawei ONT), and I guess it's the main problem here...

Comment: You are the one who indicated it was an external IP address: "it seems that config file contains IP 192.168.100.4 (external IP of Router)"

Comment: yes sorry I was not clear -  I meant 192.168.100.4 is "Internet" address of router (I added a screenshot in the text of my question), but it's a private IP because Router is sitting behind a NAT - the Huawei ONT. So question remains open - how to remotely (from Internet) access Router is a such configuration?

Comment: To reach an Intranet address like 192.168.100.4 you must forward traffic on a specific port on your Internet IP address to a specific device (i.e 192.168.100.4) If you are behind a CGNAT this essentially cannot be done.

Comment: The Huawei ONT has a public IP, so I'm not behind a CGNAT. Finally I solved the issue by forwarding port 1194 (OpenVPN port) on Huawei ONT, now I can remotely connect to my router with OpenVPN. Then I will try to configure Wake on LAN on my router, to be able to start computer behind this router through the WAN. Many thanks for your help !

Comment: 192.168.100.4 Isn’t a public address. Despite a reasonable amount of confusion you haven’t clarified your question by editing it. You should provide a detailed answer to your question.